# Method in RequestContext interface containing Map as return type

Tags: gwt, requestfactory, gwt-2.5

Am getting error while trying to do this. Am using gwt2.5 and requestfactory.

My server class looks like this:

```
public class RuleConfiguration {

    public static Map<Long, List<Operator>> getDataTypeOperatorMappings() {
        return DataTypeOperatorMappingHelper.getInstance().getValidDataTypeToOperatorMappings();
    }
}
```

And corresponding RequestContextClass looks like this

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


@Service( value = RuleConfiguration.class )
public interface RuleRequestContext extends RequestContext {

    Request<Map<Long, List<OperatorProxy>>> getDataTypeOperatorMappings();
}
```

But here am getting an error saying 
 **The type java.util.Map<"map signature">** cannot be used here

What is my mistake here? Kindly help. Thanks.

Comment: I think you cannot send map with request factory.. there is an issue https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5524

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look here https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory It doesn't list Map as a transportable type - only List and Set.  I had this problem once and solved it by breaking the map into two ArrayList where the index of one was the data for the other.

Comment: However, they list it as a transportable type in their documentation http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html#transportable so I think this is a bug.

Comment: They added Map in 2.6